# How to identifying whether passage having only spaces or line breaks or p tags using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to validate whether the passage content is empty or not. Currently I am checking by length

```
var content = "";
```

var isValidContent = validateContent(content);

```
validateContent : function(content) {
if(content.length > 0) {
   return true;
}
return false;
```

}

Now I need to handle below scenarios as those are invalid contents.

example:

```
var content = "    "; // In this case validateContent method needs to return false.
```

`var content = "<p id="cb-486206-0-20"></p> <p id="cb-791790-6-3"></p> <p id="cb-473928-2-97"></p> <p id="cb-37129-2-28"></p> <p id="cb-96325-8-15"><br /><br />&nbsp;</p> <p id="cb-437128-2-75"></p> <p id="cb-886393-6-33"></p> <p id="cb-199724-2-13"></p> <p id="cb-660479-6-26"></p> <p id="cb-493940-5-87"></p> <p id="cb-402431-2-28"></p> <p id="cb-459693-7-21"></p>";`  `// In this case validateContent method needs to return false.`

```
var content = "<p id="cb-486206-0-20"></p> <p id="cb-791790-6-3"></p> <p id="cb-473928-2-97"></p>  <p id="cb-473928-2-97"></p> <p id="cb-37129-2-28"></p>Hello <p id="cb-96325-8-15">"; //In this case validateContent method needs to return true.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the trim() function.

```
validateContent : function(content) {
    if(content.trim().length > 0) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

And if your browser doesn't support trim(), try using the following:

```
if(content.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/gm,'').length > 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing I would do is turn your string into HTML...

```
var testElement = document.createElement("div"):
testElement.innerHTML = "..."; // your string.
```

Next, I have a function that is able to parse just the text out of the HTML...

```
var getText = function (el) {
  var ret;
  var txt = [],
    i = 0;

  if (!el) {
    ret = "";
  } else if (el.nodeType === 3) {
    // No problem if it's a text node
    ret = el.nodeValue;
  } else {
    // If there is more to it, then let's gather it all.
    while (el.childNodes[i]) {
      txt[txt.length] = getText(el.childNodes[i]);
      i++;
    }
    // return the array as a string
    ret = txt.join("");
  }
  return ret;
};
```

So a

```
var result = getText(testElement).trim();
```

Then you can check the length of `result` to see if it is zero.

Answer (score 0):

When I used the jQuery it is simple to resolved the issue.

```
       var testElement = $("<div>", {id: "foo", class: "a"});
```

`$("#foo").append(content);`

`var fooConetnet = $("#foo").contents().find("body").text();`

`var isValidContent = validateContent(fooConetnet);`

`validateContent : function(fooConetnet) {`
`if(content.length > 0) {`
`return true;`
`}`
`return false;`
`}`